# RemoteMessage on flutter from nodejs, data is gone

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, firebase, vue.js

i have listening message from my **nodejs** and **vuejs (vue 2) ** to my **flutter** .

**my engine**

```
"firebase-admin": "^11.0.0", // nodejs

"firebase": "^8.2.10", // vuejs ( vue 2 )

// dependencies of my flutter project

  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.7
  firebase_core: ^1.16.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.7.2
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
```

here is my **nodejs** do

```
// sentToTopic from js
await admin
    .messaging()
    .sendToTopic(`${topic}`, message_notification, options)

message_notification: {
  title: title,
  body: headLine,
  url: req.body.url,
  other: 'other data',
  tag: req.body.tag,
  action: req.body.action,
  screen_re_fetch: `${req.body.screen_re_fetch}`
}
```

here is printed on my **vueJS** when listening to firebase

```
"data": 
  "gcm.notification.action": (...)
  "gcm.notification.other": (...)
  "gcm.notification.screen_re_fetch": (...)
  "gcm.notification.url": (...)
"fcmMessageId": (...)
"from": (...)
"notification": Object
  "body": (...)
  "tag": (...)
  "title": (...)

firebase.messaging().onMessage((payload) => { ...
```

then here is my **RemoteMessage** on flutter that use `toMap()`  on listening .

```
// retrieve on flutter (toMap()) ( RemoteMessage ) || firebaseMessage
{
  "senderId": null,
  "category": null,
  "collapseKey": "com.x.xx",
  "contentAvailable": false,
  "data": {}, // here is my question how i can retrieve the gcm.blabla , where is the data ? 
  "from": "/topics/x_test",
  "messageId": "01675065821511474%802ed552802ed552",
  "messageType": null,
  "mutableContent": false,
  "notification": {
    "title": "xxxx",
    "titleLocArgs": [],
    "titleLocKey": null,
    "body": "( COBA PARSING )",
    "bodyLocArgs": [],
    "bodyLocKey": null,
    "android": {
      "channelId": null,
      "clickAction": null,
      "color": null,
      "count": null,
      "imageUrl": null,
      "link": null,
      "priority": 0,
      "smallIcon": null,
      "sound": null,
      "ticker": null,
      "tag": "river_route",
      "visibility": 0
    },
    "apple": null,
    "web": null
  },
  "sentTime": 1675065820895,
  "threadId": null,
  "ttl": 86400
}
```

"data": {}, // here is my question how i can retrieve the gcm.blabla , where is the data ?  , am i missing on backend or .... what ?

in my mobile i looking for these data

```
 "gcm.notification.action": (...)
  "gcm.notification.other": (...)
  "gcm.notification.screen_re_fetch": (...)
  "gcm.notification.url": (...)
```

i need the action thats logic todo ( web ) alr implemented and in mobile is ongoing .
anyone else have same problem ?

Comment: ah i missing on backend , have solved by change payload . ```const message_notification = {
            data: {
              action: req.body.action.toString(),
              screen_re_fetch: `${req.body.screen_re_fetch}`.toString()
              ...
            },
            notification: {
              title: title,
              body: headLine,
              ...
            }
          }```

Comment: so its print ```data { screen_re_fetch : ``` instead of ```data { gcm.notification.screen_re_fetch
: ```